# Unique identifier and long int comparison as primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, sqldatatypes

I have seen two data types unique identifier and long int as primary keys of data table many times. Which one is better? Please share your opinions. Advantages and disadvantages over each other of both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if you don't have a specific reason to use GUIDs, use INTs.
```

ADVANTAGEOUS OF GUID:

- unique identifier is better because `guaranteed to always return a
  unique value across space and time`
- I don't know the full mechanics of creating a GUID, but I seem to
  remember that it has something to do with the MAC address on your
  network card and the system time.
- This comes in handy if you're `consolidating records from multiple
  SQL Servers into one table`, as in a data warehousing situation.

  GUIDs are also used heavily by SQL Server replication to keep track of rows when they're spread out among multiple SQL Servers.
  `DISADVANTAGEOUS OF GUID:`
- There is no way to determine the sequence in which uniqueidentifier
  values were generated. They are not suited for existing applications
  that depend on incrementing key values serially
- The main disadvantage to using GUIDs as key values is that they are
  BIG.  Indexes built on GUIDs are going to be larger and slower than
  indexes built on IDENTITY columns
- GUIDs are problematic as clustered keys because of the high
  randomness

Comment: There are 2 main problems with Guids as PKs. Their size, which you can't do anything about, and their randomness, which causes index fragmentatation and page splitting; you can avoid the latter problem by using newsequentialid() rather than newid() to get an ordered sequence of ids. If you need to generate Guids on the middle tier or client, look into the concept of "Comb". This is designed to solve the same problems as newsequentialid().